# ReferenceError: server is not defined - CkEditor5

Tags: ckeditor

I tried using CKEditor5 for my project and when I activated insert image and tried using it, It says ReferenceError: server is not defined. Here is the code:

```
class MyUploadAdapter {
    constructor( loader ) {
        this.loader = loader;
    }
    upload() {
        server.onUploadProgress( data => {
            loader.uploadTotal = data.total;
            loader.uploaded = data.uploaded;
        } );
        return loader.file
            .then( file => server.upload( file ) );
    }
    abort() {
        // Reject the promise returned from the upload() method.
        server.abortUpload();
    }
    _initRequest() {
        const xhr = this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open( 'POST', '{{ route('ck5_store')}}',true );
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN',$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
    }
    _initListeners( resolve, reject, file ) {
        const xhr = this.xhr;
        const loader = this.loader;
        const genericErrorText = `Couldn't upload file: ${ file.name }.`;
        xhr.addEventListener( 'error', () => reject( genericErrorText ) );
        xhr.addEventListener( 'abort', () => reject() );
        xhr.addEventListener( 'load', () => {
            const response = xhr.response;
            if ( !response || response.error ) {
                return reject( response && response.error ? response.error.message : genericErrorText );
            }
            resolve( {
                default: response.url
            } );
        } );
        if ( xhr.upload ) {
            xhr.upload.addEventListener( 'progress', evt => {
                if ( evt.lengthComputable ) {
                    loader.uploadTotal = evt.total;
                    loader.uploaded = evt.loaded;
                }
            } );
        }
    }
    _sendRequest( file ) {
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append( 'upload', file );
        this.xhr.send( data );
    }
    }
    function SimpleUploadAdapterPlugin( editor ) {
    editor.plugins.get( 'FileRepository' ).createUploadAdapter = ( loader ) => {
        return new MyUploadAdapter( loader );
    };
    }
    
    ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#tab-content-{{$MODULE}} form#{{$MODULE}}_form textarea[id=form_{{$MODULE}}_details]') ,
    {
        extraPlugins: [ SimpleUploadAdapterPlugin ],
    })
    .then( editor => {
    console.log( editor );
    } )
    .catch( error => {
    console.error( error );
    } );
```

Any idea on what is the problem? Already tried looking for solutions but cannot find anywhere else. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. My solution:

```js
// Starts the upload process.
upload() {
    return this.loader.file
        .then( file => new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            this._initRequest();
            this._initListeners( resolve, reject, file );
            this._sendRequest( file );
        } ) );
}

// Aborts the upload process.
abort() {
    if ( this.xhr ) {
        this.xhr.abort();
    }
}
```

I found this solution following documentation.